# Google Spreadsheets: summing cells based on value in another column

Tags: google-sheets

[image]I'm trying to sum all data in column E, where the row has a particular value in column D (in this instance '-2').

I have tried the below formula with no joy.

```
=SUM(FILTER(E2:E2203,D2:D2203="-2"))
```

I've attached a screenshot for reference.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data in Column D appears to be numeric in type. However, your formula is instructing `FILTER` to look for a string type, since you've enclosed the -2 in quotation marks. Try simply removing the quotation marks from before and after `-2`, after which `FILTER` will start looking for the true numeric value of negative two.

Comment: Success, thanks!

Comment: Great. If you would, please take a moment to mark the solution as "Best Answer." This will indicate to other contributors at a glance that the issue has been resolved, as well as allowing future site visitors to more easily find the solution.